# Library with Artifical Neural Networks for prediction for Node.js (js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, neural-network, prediction

Tell me finished library with NN for prediction for node.js.
If I search library with NN for prediction, that first line in google this is **"GitHub - cashbit/brain-predict"**. And it I can't setup, because I have namy erorr.
Other library with prediction I don't find.

Or better create yourself? Begin with one layer, then two and so far my NN will not give the right answer on my qustion?

Comment: You can create your model with tensorflow, now it supports node!

Comment: I ask question about it NN on site https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/473 And answer: this is not easy for there NN